# TabActivity and navigation inside Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tabactivity

I have done `TabActivity` with this code:

```
addTab(publication, "First", My_Files.class);
addTab(shop, "Second", Others.class); 

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

In these first and second tabs, I have `ListView`s with some context where user press it and it goes to other `Activity` with this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.app.reader.FILES");  
    intent.putExtra("publicatonName", "fileName");
    startActivity(intent);
```

But there disappear my `TabActivity`, but I still want to use it like iPhone 
`UITabBar` with `UINavigationController`

So now I am thinking that when I go to other `Activity` I need to change current `TabActivity` button class target to current and somehow my `Tab Bar Activity` should be visible.

Maybe someone could help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ActivityGroup, which will be the container of your other Activities. When the user clicks one of the buttons, you'd get a reference to the LocalActivityManager, and use it to start, and embed the inner activity.
get some experience from [here](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity) and [also](http://richipal.com/post/2624844577)